# Reading a JSON object in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm a Ruby on Rails beginner and I'm trying to convert a static website I've made into Rails app where I can store customers and quote data. I'm trying to do this as a RESTful API where my site sends a JSON object containing the customer's information. I check to see if the email in the JSON object matches any of the emails I have in my database and if it does I send back the id of that customer. If not then I create a new customer and send back that id. The problem I'm having is that no matter how I write it, my rails app is not reading the JSON data, so if I have nothing in my database it creates a customer with all null attributes and when I run it again it goes "Oh, I have customer with a null email" and returns that customer.

```
{
    "fname": "William",
    "lname": "Shakespeare",
    "email": "wshakespeare@test.com",
    "bname": "MyCompany",
    "primary": "555-555-5555",
    "secondary": ""
}
```

Here's an example of my JSON object.

Here's how my controller is looking:

```
class CustomersController < ApplicationController
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
wrap_parameters format: [:json, :xml, :url_encoded_form, :multipart_form]

def create
    @query = Customer.where(:email === params[:email])
    if @query.empty? == true
        redirect_to action: "new", status: 301
    else
        @theid = @query.first.id
        render json: {status: 'SUCCESS', message: 'Existing customer', theid:@theid}
    end
end
def new
    Customer.create(fname: params[:fname], lname: params[:lname], email: params[:email], bname: params[:bname], primary: params[:primary], secondary: params[:secondary])
    render json: {status: 'SUCCESS', message: 'New customer', theid: Customer.last.id}
end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: do you run rails as the API server? or use rails MVC as "normal"?

Comment: I think the problem lies on the mass-assignment protection since the failure is with null attribute for the customer. 
Not sure how relevant this is with the rails 5 or 6, but maybe you wanna check the rails 4 section
https://gist.github.com/joshteng/6247329

Comment: I just generated a normal default app in Rails. I wasn't aware there's a special setting for running it as an API--sorry, beginner here.